# Command that will take me to a specific column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for a command that will allow me to input a single criteria, the column I'm looking for, and then take me to that column. How can this be done in Excel?

Answer (score 4):

Fastest way I know is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (Go To) and then type your desired column, and an arbitrary row number (ex, "zz7") depending where you need to be on the column

Comment: `F5` will also open the Go To dialog.